# iPhone4 how to add/animate a UIView to appear under a UIButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation

I have a "side panel" like widget in my app that can be swiped in from the side of the screen. In order to help the users find the panel, I also added a UIButton to do the same thing - scroll the panel on and off screen.

**The view comes from a different view controller, otherwise I would've simply created an extra panel in the interface builder and positioned it properly.**

My problem is that the side panel gets positioned over the button, so if it is displayed with a button, it can only be dismissed with a gesture.

is it possible to specify at which "depth" I add a UIView when I programmatically add it in code? 
This is the snipped that slides the panel in or out within the animation block.

```
  self.audioSystemController.view.frame =CGRectMake(0,20, 120,460);
```

**I need the UIView to be shown below a UIButton**, so the button may be used to dismiss the view. I know this is redundant, but I cannot depend on the users to simply discover the side swiping gestures :/

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `insertSubview:belowSubview:` method of UIView.